# Find $A$ and $B$ so that $ \operatorname{Tr}(AB) ^{*} =0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb C) $. I thought about taking diagonal matrices, but I can't figure them out.
Edit: $X^{*}$ denotes the adjugate matrix of $X$ and $A, B \neq O_n$

Comment: If you are  just looking  for examples,  you can take $A=B=0$ or any $A$, $B$ such that $AB=0$.

Comment: What about $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$ arbitrary and $B=0$ ?

Comment: I forgot to mention, both $A$ and $B$ can't be the null matrix.

Comment: Surely you mean $Tr((AB)^*)$, not $Tr(AB)^*$...

Comment: Also, please include your actual question in the body of the post, not just in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the  even columns of $A$ are $0$ and all the odd rows of $B$ are $0$ then $AB=0$ so $Tr(AB)^{*}=0$. For example, take $a_{ij}=0$ when $j$ is even, $1$ when $j$ is odd and $b_{ij}=1$ when $i$ is even, $0$ when $i$ is odd.